# About the integrability of some function under some convergence assumption

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain and $H:=\{x\in\Omega:x_1=0\}$ a hyperplane in $\Omega$, and $\{f_k\}$  a sequence of absolutely integrable functions on $\Omega$ with $L^1$ norm  less than  $1$. Assume that $x_1\cdot f_k \to f_0$ in $L^1$ sense. as $k\to\infty$.

**Question**: Is  $\frac{f_0}{x_1}$  absolutely integrable? If so, is the $L^1$ norm of it  less than $1$?
(Note that $1/x$ is not integrable near the origin in $\mathbb{R}^1$.)

Clues: Note that,
$f_k \to f_0/{x_1}$  in $L^1$ sense as $k\to\infty$ does not hold. For example, take $\Omega=(-1,1)$,  $f_k=k/2$ on $(-1/k,1/k)$ and $=0$ somewhere else. Then $||f_k||_{L^1}=1$, and $f_0=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is YES. Convergence in $L^{1}$ implies a.e. convergence of some subsequence. If $x_1f_{k_j} \to f_0$ a.e then  Fatou's Lemma gives $\int |\frac {f_0} x| \leq \lim \inf \int |f_{k_j}| \leq 1$.